# Pytorch Categorical Cross Entropy loss function behaviour

Tags: pytorch

I have question regarding the computation made by the Categorical Cross Entropy Loss from Pytorch.
I have made this easy code snippet and because I use the argmax of the output tensor as the targets, I cannot understand why the loss is still high.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
ce_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
output = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
targets = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)
loss = ce_loss(outputs, targets)
print(loss)
```

Thanks for the help understanding it.
Best regards
Jerome

Comment: what do you mean high ? Look at my answer to see how loss can be computed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a sample data from your code with the `output`, `label` and `loss` having the following values

```
outputs =  tensor([[ 0.5968, -0.8249,  1.5018,  2.7888, -0.6125],
                   [-1.1534, -0.4921,  1.0688,  0.2241, -0.0257],
                   [ 0.3747,  0.8957,  0.0816,  0.0745,  0.2695]], requires_grad=True)requires_grad=True)

labels = tensor([3, 2, 1])
loss = tensor(0.7354, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

So let's examine the values,

If you compute the softmax output of your logits (`outputs`), using something like this `torch.softmax(outputs,axis=1)` you will get

```
probs = tensor([[0.0771, 0.0186, 0.1907, 0.6906, 0.0230],
                [0.0520, 0.1008, 0.4801, 0.2063, 0.1607],
                [0.1972, 0.3321, 0.1471, 0.1461, 0.1775]], grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)
```

So these will be your prediction probabilities.

Now cross-entropy loss is nothing but a combination of `softmax` and `negative log likelihood loss.` Hence, your loss can simply be computed using

```
loss = (torch.log(1/probs[0,3]) +  torch.log(1/probs[1,2]) + torch.log(1/probs[2,1])) / 3
```

, which is the average of the negative log of the probabilities of your true labels. The above equation evaluates to `0.7354`, which is equivalent to the value returned from the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` module.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations but first I am lost with the argmax return : I was thinking argmax will return the index of the max. So when I take the outputs tensor, I wouls have expected argmqx to return [1, 3, 4]...

Comment: In fact, why I am interested in is the Categorical Cross Entropy Loss. So by choosing a target from the argmax of the output, I was expecting to see a loss of 0 as the targets are the indexes of the max found in the outputs ....

Comment: yes it should have 1,3,4. I had messed up the index while printing. Now I have made another run and updated the numbers.

Comment: And the loss will not be `0` unless you predict the correct label with a probability of 1. If you look at the first instance where the label is `3`, we predicted that class with a portability of `0.6906`, meaning we are not 100% sure, hence we will incur some amount of loss.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking that it uses a threshold of 0.5 to say which class to predict. Now it makes sense, it is using the probability without threshold !! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: If your question is answered, can you please accept this answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Jérôme MASSOT If it used a threshold in the loss function then it wouldn't be differentiable. Every loss function needs to be "fuzzy" in a sense where even a small deviation from perfect will cause the loss to increase.